# Size of Vector from pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, capacity

I am writing a class, BitVector, where I have a method that returns the capacity of a BitVector.  My thought was to call the std::vector capacity(), but I am getting an error I'm a bit confused about.  Below is my method:

```
int BitVector::Size() {
int size = (int) this->bitVector().capacity();
}
```

The error I am running into is "expression proceeding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type.  What is the issue here?

Additional background info about my class:

My BitVector class has the usual public constructors, deconstructors, etc. and then a private pointer to a vector as follows:

```
private:
std::vector<uint8_t>* bitVector;
```

In my constructor, I point the pointer to a vector on the heap like so:

```
BitVector::BitVector(int numBits) {
this->bitVector = new std::vector<uint8_t> (numBits, 0);
}
```

Comment: `bitVector` is a pointer, it must be dereferenced, `this->bitVector().capacity();` -> `bitVector()->capacity();`.

Comment: Do you really need to use a pointer to your vector?

Comment: Probably not, would it make more sense to just have the vector? I do need it on the heap, though.  So I thought the pointer would make sense?  Very new C++ programmer here!! Thanks for the advice

Comment: @Vic vectors store all their actual data on the heap so it's hard to find reasons to have pointers to them :)

Comment: In fact a vector is basically a *dynamic array* with all the fiddly bits done for you behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe you need a pointer here, just declare it as:

```
private:
std::vector<uint8_t> bitVector;
```

You do not need `this->` prefix to access class members, and `int` is not a good type to express a capacity value (what is the means of capacity whose value is negative?). So, in your function I would do:

```
int BitVector::Size() {
   auto size = bitVector.capacity();
}
```

but if really needs a pointer, you can do:

```
int BitVector::Size() {
   auto size = bitVector->capacity();
}
```

using pointer derreference

**Edited**

As pointed by @Donnie, the return type of this function becomes wrong too. If you are using C++14, and assuming that you want to return the `size` variable, you can make your life simple by just letting the compiler uses what `bitvector.capacity()` is using to hold its values. So your function should be:

```
auto BitVector::Size() {
   auto size = bitVector.capacity();
   return size;
}
```

Comment: You should probably return something from those functions.

Answer (score 1):

`bitVector` is just a member, not a function.  It is also a pointer.

`int size = (int)this->bitVector->capacity();`

Also, note that a `std::vector<bool>` is [already specialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) into a bit vector (using 1 bit per bool), so you're re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Thank you! So I don't think I understand the difference between doing bitVector.capacity() and bitVector->capacity().  I thought -> meant dereference.

Comment: It does.  Your `bitVector` is a pointer, so you must deference it to access any members of it.